# How to style default confirm box with only css?

Tags: css, confirm

I would like to style standard window.confirm without using any additional JavaScript code, only with CSS. Is it even possible? And if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: A example would be a great step in the right direction.

Comment: @Kyle I don't see why his question needs an example. He explained it perfectly fine.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is not possible. This window is displayed by the browser using the platform's UI kit. It's not in the DOM, not visible from the CSS or Javascript, there's nothing you can do.

However, some very simple jQuery code can do the trick. How about `$('a').confirm();` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, was hoping there was a possibility to do it without any plugins. :) Guess I'll have to use JQuery after all.

Answer (score 15):

`confirm();` alerts cannot be styled, they are generic to the browser. If you want to style an alert, try alternatives such as [boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/), or the [jQuery dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

[Here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/) is a tutorial about how a custom confirm alert can be created in jQuery and styled with CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much! A very helpful tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question.
But I felt the need to pass this info here.
I noticed that you can "style" the confirm with special characters, such as \n, \t, \r, ... so on.

Comment: However, those aren't styles. Styles would be such things as the font, size, color, and so forth. You're correct in the ability to use those though.

Comment: Not styles, but needed to add a line break so ty this helped - upvoted