# How to provide span for a Jquery confirmation box?

Tags: jquery, html, confirmation

I have a `confirmation box`. I have to provide a `span` along with the message in the confirmation. To this `span` i have to provide certain `style`. How can i did it.

**I tried like this..**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var c = confirm("Warning "+ < span > +"Do you want to delete?" + < /span>);
        if (c == true) {
        $("#para").remove();
        } else {
        //somthing here
        }
    });
```

but nothing is happened.If i remove the `span` from here the code is working..So how can i provide this `span`. Is this possible..Any help is appreciated..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x3pqw/)

Comment: You cannot put HTML inside the text of a `confirm` dialog box, so I'm not sure what your question is about, or why you're trying to do what you are.

Comment: Why is the `span` out of the string concatenation? It should be part of it. But it won't work anyway, as the `confirm` dialog doesn't accept HTML markup.

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css

Answer (score 2):

`confirm` dialogs cannot contain HTML: only text. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4cd6C/1/

If you use `<span>`, it will show as text. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4cd6C/