# Yii change confirm dialogbox layout

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using cGridview in Yii. 
When i click on delete link. its shows confirmation box which is default browser confirm box. I want to change it css and layout.

Please guide me how can i change confirmbox layout in Yii 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

The confirm box used in this case is original js confirm box. So you better google [*style js confirm*](https://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=style%20js%20confirm) and find the best tool for yours.

Some posts are helpful:

- [How to style default confirm box with only css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css)
- http://skycube.net/2009/04/26/style-up-your-javascript-confirm-boxes/
- http://www.bitrepository.com/stylish-javascript-dialog-boxes.html