# Styling a jquery CONFIRM box

Tags: jquery

The script below performs certain checks.

If a user attempts to book reservation for less than four hours, an alert is raised advising the user that a minimum of four hours is required.

If user attempts to book a reservation for over four hours, again, user is advised that additional charges may accrue for any additional hours after the initial four hours.

Then a confirm box is presented to the user to click Ok to continue or cancel to stay within four hours.

Everything works great.

However, we would like to make the confirm box a bit more appealing to the eyes.

Any ideas how to do this?

Here is my entire working script and thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () {
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker();
                $('#timeStart').timepicker({ showPeriod: true,
                    onHourShow: OnHourShowCallback,
                    onMinuteShow: OnMinuteShowCallback
                });

                $("#txtToDate").datepicker();
                $('#timeEnd').timepicker({ showPeriod: true,
                    onHourShow: OnHourShowCallback,
                    onMinuteShow: OnMinuteShowCallback
                });
                function OnHourShowCallback(hour) {
                    if ((hour > 20) || (hour < 6)) {
                        return false; // not valid
                    }
                    return true; // valid
                }
                function OnMinuteShowCallback(hour, minute) {
                    if ((hour == 20) && (minute >= 30)) { return false; } // not valid
                    if ((hour == 6) && (minute < 30)) { return false; }   // not valid
                    return true;  // valid
                }
                $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
                    var sDate = $("#txtFromDate").val();
                    var sTime = $("#timeStart").val();

                    var eDate = $("#txtToDate").val();
                    var eTime = $("#timeEnd").val();

                    var startDate = new Date(sDate + " " + sTime).getHours();
                    var endDate = new Date(eDate + " " + eTime).getHours();

                    //Calulate the time difference
                    var hourDiff = endDate - startDate;
                    //alert(hourDiff);

                    //Check if hour difference is less than 4 hours and show the message accordingly
                    if (hourDiff < 4) {
                        alert("A mininum of 4 hours is required!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    //Here you add the check condition if you are above the 4 hours time frame
                    //Add the check condition if the user is above the 4 hours time frame
                    if (hourDiff > 4) {
                        var r = confirm("There may be additional fees for going over the 4 hours!");
                        if (r == true) { // pressed OK
                            return true;
                        } else { // pressed Cancel
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) is not jQuery, and it can't be styled. You'll have to use something like jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: `r = false;
$($("<div>There may be additional fees for going over the 4 hours!</div>")).dialog({
      closeOnEscape: false,
  resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
  buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
     r = true;
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
     r = false;
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
   close: function() {
    return r;
   }
    });`

Comment: can you do it in a way that I can give you credit for your solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not since the question has been closed already.  glad it works for you!  cheers

Comment: I'd like to add that this question did **not** ask about styling the confirm box with CSS and so is not a duplicate. This being the case, I'd ask that @David Thomas reopen the question.

Comment: @billynoah, thank you for mentioning that.

I am already fed up with this site.

They have a bunch of fools who are given the power to destroy posters.

That fool claims this question has been asked before but failed to show the actual question.

This is a great forum but I just don't understand how they let certain members determine the fate of others like me.

This is likely to be my last post here. Screw this!

Comment: Fair enough, I've reopened; I'd suggest that calling us, in this case specifically me, 'fools' is possibly not the best way to have us help out though. Notifying us that it was a mistake is usually enough.

Comment: Note that if the question was *not* about styling the confirm box with CSS, then the CSS tag is not necessary to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm boxes [can not be styled with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css), as your CSS tag suggests.  Your best bet is to go with a [jQueryUI dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).  In fact, there is a [specific example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) of what you are trying to do on the jQueryUI page.