# Issue with the way data is displayed in confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple text boxes where I can type a material name and in another box I can type the material price.

When the user clicks submit I am displaying a confirm box with the entered material(s) and price(s). In this confirm box I want to show all entered matr_name with the associated matr_price (one per line). I just can not seem to make it display as I want, the below script outputs like this:

matr_name 
matr_price 
matr_name 
matr_price 
etc.

**I want it to display like this:**

matr_name: matr_price 
 
matr_name: matr_price 
 
matr_name: matr_price 
 
etc.

All I got is the below script which gives me the correct output, just not displayed as I want it in the confirm box.

**Script**

```
var matr_name = $("input[name*='matr']").map(function() {
return $(this).val()}).get().join('\n');
var confirm_form = confirm("Rep:\n" + matr_name);
console.log("Mart.: " + matr_name);
if(confirm_form == true)
  {
return true;
  } 
else {
return false;
      }
    }
```

**Part of the form:**

```
    <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_name[]" id="matr_name" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_price[]" id="matr_price"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_name[]" id="matr_name" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_price[]" id="matr_price"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_name[]" id="matr_name" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_price[]" id="matr_price"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_name[]" id="matr_name" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="matr_price[]" id="matr_price"/></td>
        </tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" id="submit_id" class="submit" value="Done" onclick="javascript:return show_confirm();"/>
```

Comment: DO NOT use the same id for more than one item in the same page, it is illegal

Comment: ... Thank you @AndreaLigios I will use classes instead.

Comment: Or use ids with a numeric identifier at the end, like matr_name_1, matr_name_2, etc

Comment: You want CSS here... have you tried it?

Comment: ... Got it. Other than that do you have any suggestions on how to solve my issue?

Comment: ... @SandeepNayak Are you sure you can do that with CSS? Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css

Comment: @Nomis: Thanks!..dint know that one...Just wanted to be sure if you gave CSS a try.

Comment: ... @AndreaLigios reg. I changed the id´s so they are unique + I am using classes (`.attr('class')`) instead in Guffa ex. below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put different strings after the value depending on the name:

```
var matr_name = $("input[name*='matr']").map(function() {
  return $(this).val() + ($(this).attr('name') == 'matr_name[]' ? ': ' : '\n');
}).get().join('');
```

or:

```
var matr_name = $("input[name*='matr']").map(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'matr_name[]') {
    return $(this).val() + ': ';
  } else {
    return $(this).val() + '\n';
  }
}).get().join('');
```

Comment: Thats pretty tough for somebody who is new to JS :)

Comment: @SandeepNayak: Yes, you have a point there. It's not tougher than the code that already is there, but I guess it was mostly copied from somewhere in the first place. I added a more readable version.

Comment: ... @SandeepNayak yes indeed, but after I changed `.attr('name')` to `.attr('id')`, it does exactly what I want. Now I just have to play around to understand exactly what the code does.

Comment: @Nomis: Right, I missed the brackets in the name. You can just add them to the value that you compare with. You should really remove those duplicates id's, they don't work properly (or at least avoid using them at all).

Comment: ... thank you @Guffa will do and reg. the id´s I will use classes instead.