# Styling message box

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to give some style for the message box which pops up after pressing logout button (just confirmation window). My jQuery code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a[data-post]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var message = $this.data("post");

    if (message && !confirm(message)) {
        return;
    }

    $("<form>")
        .attr("method", "post")
        .attr("action", $this.attr("href"))
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .submit();

   });

});
```

_Layout part:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Logout")" data-post="Are you sure you want to Logout?"><div class="navFont">Logout</div></a>
```

**Problem** Im not sure how to call the message box in css file to give it some style.

Comment: `confirm` dialog is default to browsers. These cannot be modified using CSS. You can look at options like [jQuery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: How can I make it not default?

Comment: Refer this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply styles to `confirm` or `alert` boxes since they will be different to respective browsers and they cannot be `overridden`. You will find plenty of `jquery plugin` to do this task. One of them which is my personal best for these kind of requirements is **[`Sweet-Alert`](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)** plugin which has lot of options and for your requirement, it can be implemented as below:

**Steps**

---

- [**`Download the files`**](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/archive/master.zip)
- Include necessary **[`Sweet-Alert`](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)** reference files.

**Example**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert.css">
<script src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

- Modify your `click` event to include **[`Sweet-Alert`](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)**

**Example**

```
$("a[data-post]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var message = $this.data("post");
    swal({   
       title: "Are you sure?",   
       text: message,  //Your message here
       type: "warning",   
       showCancelButton: true,   
       confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
       confirmButtonText: "Yes",   
       closeOnConfirm: false 
     }, function(){
        //this gets executed if user hits `Yes`
        $("<form>")
         .attr("method", "post")
         .attr("action", $this.attr("href"))
         .appendTo(document.body)
         .submit();
        });
      });
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)