# Angular confirmation box style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, confirmation

After I login in my app which I made in Angularjs, first step is that initial function show confirmation box. That is regular confirmation box, without any style. My question is how I can stylize that box with CSS, and add some text too, if my function is :

```
function versionCheck() {
  if ($window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    vm.starting = true;
    dataService.restartVersion()
        .then(function onSuccess(data) {
            vm.data = data.response;
        }).catch(function onReject(response) {
    }).finally(function () {
        vm.starting = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Again I will remind that I immediately start with this function after login, without press button or something else, automatically.

Any helps?

Comment: I really didn't know about adding class, I will look now

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css

Comment: If you need stylised modals then look at what bootstrap can provide.You won't be using $window.confirm however.

Comment: I tried regular bootstrap modal, [http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp], but I need button to press to get modal, how to implement this solution in my function?

Comment: You should do something like, $('#myModal').modal({show: true}), check the full docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals and the section entitled "Varying modal content based on trigger button"

Answer (score 1):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This is the Angular Material Design way of customizing dialog boxes.
# $mdDialog.confirm() and $mdDialog.show will solve this issue.
# I would create a totally different function to handle the dataService
# And have the versionCheck() just handling the confirmation dialog
# as shown below.

function versionCheck() {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Cancel confirmation')
        .textContent('Are you sure?')
        .ariaLabel('Are you sure?')
        .ok('Ok')
        .cancel('Cancel');

    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(
        function() {
            $state.go('login');
            );
        }
    );
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```