# Angular confirmation box: how do I make it *look* like a dialog box?

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I'm trying to write a simple "yes/no" confirmation box in Angular 8.3.

In C#, Java, JS, etc etc it would be a one-liner: `var result = MessageBox.Show("Click Me", "My Dialog", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);`

In Angular, it seems the preferred approach is to use a [Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).  It kind of works - but it doesn't look or behave like I would expect.  Specifically:

[image]

- I'd like a pop-up window
- With a border
- Centered on the screen
- I'd also like "Yes" to be the default option, clearly highlighted.

Q: How can I do this?

NOTE: I like this link ... but it seems obsolete: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106139/3135317

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...    
import { ConfirmationDlgComponent } from './common/confirmation-dlg.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    ConfirmationDlgComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [ ConfirmationDlgComponent ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**confirmation-dlg.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  template: `
  <h3 mat-dialog-title>{{dlgTitle}}</h3>
  <mat-dialog-content>{{dlgMessage}}</mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>No</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>Yes</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
  `
})
export class ConfirmationDlgComponent {
  dlgTitle: string;
  dlgMessage: string;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmationDlgComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public extraData) {
    this.dlgTitle = extraData.dlgTitle;
    this.dlgMessage = extraData.dlgMessage;
  }
}
```

**list-contents.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteContact(contact)"> Delete Contact </button>
```

**list-contents.component.ts**

```
deleteContact(contact: Contact) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDlgComponent, {
      hasBackdrop: true,
      height: '250px',
      position: {top: '', bottom: '', left: '', right: ''},
      data: {
        dlgTitle: 'Delete (' + contact.name + ')',
        dlgMessage: 'Really delete this contact?'
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        console.log('Yes clicked');
        this.contactsService.deleteContact(contact).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log('loadContacts', data);
            this.loadContacts();
          },
          err => {
            console.error('deleteContact', err);
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with Material Dialog as it is? I know you specified the attributes you'd like for the dialog, but I'm not sure how what you want differs from what Material Dialog provides?

Comment: Q: What's wrong?  A: I'd like a pop-up window. With a border. Centered on the screen. I'd also like "Yes" to be the default option, clearly highlighted.  All of which, I imagine, *should* be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was add this line to `styles.css`:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

[image]

From this link:

https://appdividend.com/2019/02/11/angular-modal-tutorial-with-example-angular-material-dialog/

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry about that. I just now realized in your original screenshot the dialog content was on the page and not styled as a dialog.